# how to map one to many optional recursive relationship in Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

I have entity call Answers and answer entity can have multiple child answers, i.e.  Collection I am struggling to map this in my model configuration class.

### Model Class

```
public class AnswerDataModel : IDataModel<Guid>
{
    public AnswerDataModel()
    {

        SubQuestionAnswers = new HashSet<AnswerDataModel>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AnswerDataModel> SubQuestionAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

### Answer Configuration class

```
public class AnswerEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AnswerDataModel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AnswerDataModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Answers");
        builder.HasKey(answer => answer.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(answer => answer.Question)
            .WithMany(question => question.Answers)
            .HasForeignKey(answer => answer.QuestionId);

       builder
             .????????  // how to map recursive Answer Collections as subQuestionAnswer??

    }
}
```

Comment: I have done like this;  builder
                .HasMany(answer => answer.SubQuestionAnswers)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(answer => answer.Id);  but I cannot see any recursive relationship in sql server management studio diagram

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You start with the collection navigation property:

```
builder
    .HasMany(answer => answer.SubQuestionAnswers)
```

The rest depends of the presence of the inverse navigation property and explicit FK property in the model.

(A) The original model (no inverse navigation property, no explicit FK property)

```
.WithOne()
.HasForeignKey("ParentId")
.IsRequired(false);
```

(B) With inverse navigation property added to the model

```
public virtual AnswerDataModel Parent { get; set; }
```

it would be:

```
.WithOne(answer => answer.Parent);
```

(C) With explcit FK property added to the model

```
public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
```

it would be:

```
.WithOne()
.HasForeignKey(answer => answer.ParentId);
```

(D) With both inverse navigation and explcit FK properties added to the model

```
public virtual AnswerDataModel Parent { get; set; }
public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
```

it would be:

```
.WithOne(answer => answer.Parent)
.HasForeignKey(answer => answer.ParentId);
```

(`HasForeignKey` here can be skipped because it's by convention)